# SQL Update Trigger that inserts old values into audit table and only fires if two specific columns are being updated, otherwise returns error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016

I need to **record** all **previous addresses and postcodes** when they are updated in the Customer table.

**Business requirement: Addresses cannot be changed without also updating the postcode and vice versa.**

A mechanism to prevent this is required along with appropriate **error messages.**

I already created the table:

```
create table tblCustomerAudit
(
CustomerID int identity(1,1) not null,
CustomerName nvarchar(255) null,
CustomerAddress nvarchar(255) null,
CustomerPostcode nvarchar(255) null,
CardNumber nvarchar(255) null,
)
go

alter table tblCustomerAudit
add constraint FK_CustomerAudit
foreign key(CustomerID)
references CstmrEng.tblCustomer(CustomerID)
```

What would trigger look like? please help!

Comment: `Addresses cannot be changed without also updating the postcode and vice versa.` - Uh, sure they can.  Say I live with my parents, but am a customer.  Then their neighbor sells their house to me.  My address will change, but it's unlikely my postcode is going to be any different.  This also ignores things like being issued a new postcode (or making a typo of the postcode), where the rest of the address doesn't change.

Comment: But thats not the question whether it makes sense logically or not... thats the business requirement, wtf m8?

Comment: Perhaps they meant "both parameters must be provided, if either is", regardless of the actual values?

Comment: exactly, both values must be provided for trigger to fire, they just happen to be address and postcode

Comment: So the trigger would check the old and new addr/postcode and only allow it to go through if the condition was met.  Now, where to you want to store the old values?  Same table (like a SCD-2) or audit table or what?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do this with a stored procedure? Just be aware that stored procedures are not magic pixie dust, and maintaining them can be a nightmare.

You could have your trigger call a stored procedure that handles the particular constraint between CustomerAddress and CustomerPostcode.

This code is untested and may very well not work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateCustomerAddressAndPostcode @CustomerID INT, @CustomerAddress NVARCHAR(255), @CustomerPostcode NVARCHAR(255)
AS BEGIN

IF (@CustomerAddress IS NULL OR @CustomerAddress = '')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Customer address must be present to modify Customer table.';
    THROW;
END

IF (@CustomerPostcode IS NULL OR @CustomerPostcode = '')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Customer postcode must be present to modify Customer table.';
    THROW;
END

INSERT INTO tblCustomerAudit (CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerPostcode, CardNumber)
    SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerPostcode, CardNumber FROM Customer where CustomerID = @CustomerID;

-- just printing the table for example
SELECT * FROM tblCustomerAudit

-- make the change to Customer here or in the trigger

END
GO


CREATE TRIGGER CustomerTrigger 
   ON  [dbo].[Customer] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
DECLARE @CustomerID int
DECLARE @CustomerAddress nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @CustomerPostcode nvarchar(255)

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- verify the data
    EXEC UpdateCustomerAddressAndPostcode @CustomerID, @CustomerAddress, @CustomerPostcode

    -- do the Customer change here or in the stored procedure

END
```

Comment: Thanks but it HAS to be a trigger.

Comment: Why does it have to be trigger?  A sproc gives you more control

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend a store procedure to control the update, insert, and delete, so you'll use the store procedure to pass the values before it goes to the table. If you use a trigger, then the values will be actually changed, then the trigger will be fired, and from the trigger you'll have to re-update the table with the old values if your conditions met. So, this is a kind of redundancy for me, which is why I recommended a store procedure to handle everything before change the table values.

anyhow, you can still use triggers with the advantage of deleted and inserted tables :

```
CREATE TRIGGER CustomerUpdate ON   tblCustomerAudit
   FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE 
        @CustomerID             INT
    ,   @New_CustomerAddress    nvarchar(255)
    ,   @New_CustomerPostcode   nvarchar(255)
    ,   @Old_CustomerAddress    nvarchar(255)
    ,   @Old_CustomerPostcode   nvarchar(255)

    SELECT 
        @CustomerID             = CustomerID 
    ,   @Old_CustomerAddress    = CustomerAddress
    ,   @Old_CustomerPostcode   = CustomerPostcode
    FROM 
        deleted

    SELECT 
        @New_CustomerAddress    =   CustomerAddress
    ,   @New_CustomerPostcode   =   CustomerPostcode
    FROM
        tblCustomerAudit 
    WHERE 
        CustomerID = @CustomerID


    IF @Old_CustomerAddress = @New_CustomerAddress OR @New_CustomerPostcode = @Old_CustomerPostcode 
    BEGIN 
        -- IF one of them matches return the old values
        UPDATE tblCustomerAudit
        SET 
            CustomerAddress  = @Old_CustomerAddress
        ,   CustomerPostcode = @Old_CustomerPostcode
        WHERE 
            CustomerID = @CustomerID

        -- display an error message 
        RAISERROR( 'You need to change both address and postcode to save the new values', 18 , 0);

    END






END
```

Comment: That won't work correctly.  assumes  only one row per update.  That's not guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo.bar ON foo.mytable
AFTER UPDATE  
AS  
IF (@@ROWCOUNT_BIG  = 0)
RETURN;
IF EXISTS (SELECT *  
           FROM foo.mytable AS t
           JOIN inserted AS i   
           ON t.mykey = i.mykey
           WHERE i.addr <> t.addr AND i.post = t.post -- address changes but post code doesn't
              OR i.post <> t.post AND i.addr = t.addr -- post code changes by address doesn't
          )  
BEGIN  
RAISERROR ('invalid changes', 16, 1);  
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
RETURN   
END;
```

GO